# Get administrative boundaries using quickOSM plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, query, quickosm

I'm trying to access the administrative boundaries of different countries using the quickOSM plugin in qgis. The query runs successfully but with no results. This is the query I try to run with the error message :
[image]

(I clicked on run query and got the yellow message "successful query, but no results" .

What is the mistake here? How can I access the administrative boundaries of countries using quick OSM?

**EDIT: I tried this as suggested by Grzegorz Sapijaszko but this is still not working:**
[image]

Comment: In my experience `admin_level=*` yields always results.

Comment: @Erik what do you mean? can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks. But adding `admin_level=` is a subset from the query `boundary=administrative`, I wonder why there isn't any result ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `admin_level = xxx` to your query, like:

[image]

*Edit:*

what happens, if you execute it as a query? Like:

[image]

Or maybe try to set up the Overpass API url (mine was empty while running the tests and it worked):

[image]

Comment: I have tried this but still no results, see my original post I added a screenshot

Comment: No clue, would you mind to try the query itself, and/or to set up permanently Overpass API?